# Unity 3D Game variable contains definition but still shows error CS0117: 'PlayerCarController' does not contain a definition for 'accelarationForce'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a 3D unity game and I was writing a script for a timer. I used accelerationForce and after I was done writing the code it said that PlayerCarController (other script) does not contain a definition for accelerationForce. Every help is greatly appreciated. Here the 2 problems:

Assets\Scripts\Timer.cs(30,31): error CS0117: 'PlayerCarController' does not contain a definition for 'accelarationForce'

Assets\Scripts\Timer.cs(39,31): error CS0117: 'PlayerCarController' does not contain a definition for 'accelarationForce'

PlayerCarController Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCarController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Wheels collider")]
    public WheelCollider frontLeftWheelCollider;
    public WheelCollider frontRightWheelCollider;
    public WheelCollider backLeftWheelCollider;
    public WheelCollider backRightWheelCollider;

    [Header("Wheels Transfrom")]
    public Transform frontLeftWheelTransfrom;
    public Transform frontRightWheelTransfrom;
    public Transform backLeftWheelTransfrom;
    public Transform backRightWheelTransfrom;

    [Header("Car Engine")]
    public float accelerationForce = 300f;
    public float breakingForce = 3000f;
    private float presentBreakForce = 0f;
    private float presentAcceleration = 0f;

    [Header("Car Steering")]
    public float wheelsTorque = 35f;
    private float presentTurnAngle = 0f;



    private void Update()
    {
        MoveCar();
        CarSteering();
        ApplyBreaks();
    }

    private void MoveCar()
    {
        //AWD
        frontLeftWheelCollider.motorTorque = presentAcceleration;
        frontRightWheelCollider.motorTorque = presentAcceleration;
        backLeftWheelCollider.motorTorque = presentAcceleration;
        backRightWheelCollider.motorTorque = presentAcceleration;

        presentAcceleration = accelerationForce * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
     }

     private void CarSteering()
     {
          presentTurnAngle = wheelsTorque * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
          frontLeftWheelCollider.steerAngle = presentTurnAngle;
          frontRightWheelCollider.steerAngle = presentTurnAngle;

          SteeringWheels(frontLeftWheelCollider, frontLeftWheelTransfrom);
          SteeringWheels(frontRightWheelCollider, frontRightWheelTransfrom);
          SteeringWheels(backLeftWheelCollider, backLeftWheelTransfrom);
          SteeringWheels(backRightWheelCollider, backRightWheelTransfrom);
    }

    void SteeringWheels(WheelCollider WC, Transform WT)
    {

          Vector3 position;
          Quaternion rotation;


          WC.GetWorldPose(out position, out rotation);

          WT.position = position;
          WT.rotation = rotation;
      }

      public void ApplyBreaks()
      {
            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
                presentBreakForce = breakingForce;

            else
               presentBreakForce = 0f;


            frontLeftWheelCollider.brakeTorque = presentBreakForce;
            frontRightWheelCollider.brakeTorque = presentBreakForce;
            backLeftWheelCollider.brakeTorque = presentBreakForce;
            backRightWheelCollider.brakeTorque = presentBreakForce;
    }
}
```

Timer Script (the one where i get the problems from)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Timer")]
    public float countDownTimer = 5f;

    [Header("Things to stop")]
    public PlayerCarController playerCarController;
    public OpponentCar OpponentCar;
    public OpponentCar OpponentCar1;
    public OpponentCar OpponentCar2;
    public OpponentCar OpponentCar3;
    public OpponentCar OpponentCar4;

    public Text countDownText;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(TimeCount());
    }

    void Update()
    {
      if(countDownTimer > 1)
      {
          PlayerCarController.accelarationForce = 0f;
          OpponentCar.movingSpeed = 0f;
          OpponentCar1.movingSpeed = 0f;
          OpponentCar2.movingSpeed = 0f;
          OpponentCar3.movingSpeed = 0f;
          OpponentCar4.movingSpeed = 0f;
          }
          else if(countDownTimer == 0)
          {
          PlayerCarController.accelarationForce = 300f;
          OpponentCar.movingSpeed = 12f;
          OpponentCar1.movingSpeed = 13f;
          OpponentCar2.movingSpeed = 14f;
          OpponentCar3.movingSpeed = 9f;
          OpponentCar4.movingSpeed = 8f;



          }
      }


    IEnumerator TimeCount()
    {

        while(countDownTimer > 0)
        {
            countDownText.text = countDownTimer.ToString();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            countDownTimer--;
        }

        countDownText.text = "GO";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        countDownText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You spelled "acceleration" wrong.  Your class defines `accelerationForce` but the other class is trying to use `accelarationForce` (with an `a` instead of `e` as the 6th character).

Comment: This is so embarassing. Thank you, i use atom for writing scripts and probably couldnt tell if it was an A or an E. Though now it says Assets\Scripts\Timer.cs(39,11): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PlayerCarController.accelerationForce'

Comment: @Davinci That's another typo... you're using `PlayerCarController.accelerationForce` instead of `playerCarController.accelerationForce` (lower case `p` to use the field instead of capital `P` to use the class itself).

Comment: I dont know where i was looking. thank you though for answering my stupid questions, have a great day